# Inference in generic function parameters

Tags: typescript

Basic type inference is very straightforward in TypeScript:

```
const bar = foo(); // bar: <type that foo returns>
```

Considering that generic parameter default value is `{}`, it would be reasonable to expect that the code below will cause type error, because callback function returns `number` and not `{}`:

```
function foo<T = {}>(callback: () => T): T {
    return callback();
}

let bar = foo(() => 1); // bar: number
```

But it's known that `T` is inferred from callback return value, it is:

```
function foo<number>(callback: () => number): number
```

How exactly does this happen and where is this behaviour prescribed? A quote from documentation or explanations from TypeScript developers that shed some light would be appreciated.

Is it possible to force `T` to be default value (`{}` or whatever specified in `<T = ...>`) and not be inferred in `foo(() => 1)` call? This may be desirable behaviour in some cases.

If there other counter-intuitive cases of inference in TypeScript, their mention is welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, you answer your own question:

> Considering that generic parameter **default** value is `{}`

By using the syntax `<T = {}>` you are assigning a default, not a requirement. The default will only be used when TypeScript is unable to infer the type of `T` through other means.

If you want to explicitly limit the form that `T` can take, you should be using generic constraints rather than a default. (See the *Generic Constraints* section in the [TypeScript Generics documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html))

For instance, using the example you presented:

```
function foo<T extends object>(callback: () => T): T {
  return callback();
}

let bar = foo(() => 1); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'object'
```

You can even still provide a default value alongside the constraint, by using `<T extends object = {}>`

As for your somewhat different question:

> Is it possible to force `T` to be default value [...] and not be inferred

Yes, you can always provide a type when you make the function invocation to override the inference. For example:

```
function foo<T extends object = {}>(callback: () => T): T {
  return callback();
}

interface User { name: string }
const user: User = { name: 'Bob' };

let bar = foo<{}>(() => user); // bar: {}
```

Even though I've passed a `T` of type `User`, I explicitly declare the generic for the invocation and the output will use that generic value instead.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I consider this counter-intuitive, because there's nothing to *infer* - there is already *default* value. I even considered this a bug, but it looks more of a feature. There's too much in TS that should be empirically deduced, that's why I asked for a reference. `T extends` looks like we're on the right track... but sadly this won't work if T is allowed to be explicitly specified as `foo<number>(...)` but should stick to `{}` for `foo(...)`. Do you have ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Any generic that you explicitly specify still has to conform to the constraints of the generic. If the generic is typed as `T extends object` then `foo<number>` will error out, saying `Type 'number' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'`. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? If you always want it to be typed as `{}` you should not use a generic and just have the return type be `{}`, although that doesn't seem like a useful scenario.

Comment: I used `{}` for simplicity because it's default param value. Let's say foo processes errors, and by default `T` is `Error`, and `foo(...)` call should be restricted to `Error` return value. But an error can by anything if T is passed explicitly, `foo<string>(...)`.