# What is a Promise<{}>?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, events, promise

I want to create a promise which settles when a WebSocket connects.

```
import * as WebSocket from "ws"

let ws = WebSocket("ws://example.com")

function foo(echo: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => ws.once("open", () => resolve(echo)));
}
```

In VS Code, the foo function infers as yielding `Promise<{}>`.

1. What a `Promise<{}>`?
2. More generally, how do I get this to refer a `Promise<string>`?  Am I misunderstanding [Trigger Promise when an event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933088/trigger-promise-when-an-event-fires) ?

Comment: Maybe `return new Promise<string>(...);`?

Comment: Ugh, just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967176/what-is-type
Is {} in inferred types always a compiler issue?

Comment: Possibly. I haven't worked _that_ much with TypeScript yet, but I can check out the global `.d.ts` files for an explanation of this particular shortcoming if you'd like.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In that case, I would want to know why TS can't infer the type here, and why it's putting a weird {} in the inferred type...
(sorry, this ought to have been in reply to the `Promise<string>` suggestion)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Is there a way I can do that myself?

Comment: FWIW [here's the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5254) that discusses this limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics have `{}` (empty object) as [default parameter value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

`Promise` is a generic. Since generic type cannot be inferred from `resolve` argument due to TypeScript limitations, it's `{}`, or an empty object, by default.

It should be:

```
function foo(echo: string) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => ws.once("open", () => resolve(echo)));
}
```

Comment: Hrm, interesting.  Do you have any links/sources?  I'd like to know more about these limitations so I know when I run into them in the future.  EDIT: Oh, it seems to be in the default parameter value link.

Comment: (I actually upvoted you, FYI, this comment is not a criticism of your answer) I was looking for these "TypeScript limitations" myself, but the `lib.es2015.promise.d.ts` defines `new` as `new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;` so given that `echo` is declared as `string`, I can't seem to wrap my head around the fact that TS can't infer `T` from the value passed to `resolve`.

Comment: Wait, I don't see anything in the link about having the empty object as the default parameter value.

Comment: It's just how generics work. There are some quirks that aren't described anywhere because TS reference is basically a guide (see this generic question for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262700/inference-in-generic-function-parameters ) The connection between Promise generic type and resolve argument type is too complex. It works only in one direction. I.e., generic type cannot be inferred but if wrong type was provided, it will cause type error, e.g. `Promise<number>` and `resolve(echo)`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks. I'm not aware of what the complexities exactly are, but I guess that T will be harder to infer if there are multiple points it could be inferred from. I'm sure there's open issue somewhere in TS repo with 'Discussion needed' label that addresses this issue but wasn't assigned to anybody.